# what is the difference between these two type of addressing

Tags: c++, c, string, character

Here even though the base address are same then why the output is not the same, please describe how the working is done in the first printf statement ??

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
char c[2]="a";
printf("%c\n",c);
printf("%c",c[0]);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The difference is, that this `printf("%c\n",c);` statement is wrong.

Comment: `printf("%c", c)` is used to print a `char` type. `c` is of a `pointer` type. `c[0]` is a `char` type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first `printf()` statement you have **Undefined Behaviour**. Anything can happen. In this instance you were unlucky and got a result you think you can explain (but really you can't: it's **UB**).

In the second `printf()` statement (ignoring the fact that **UB** has occurred and the whole program is thus invalid), the first element of the array `c` is printed.

Comment: Explaining a bit more, with `printf` it's up to the programmer to make sure that the argument matches the specifier.. if you get it wrong then undefined behaviour results. Some friendly compilers may give a warning.

Comment: thanks for you time,but can you give a reference from which i can dig it much deeper. I am a newbie and trying to build my concepts here, thanks in advance @MattMcNabb

Comment: My usual reference is [POSIX.1-2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/). Some people (me included) also like the text of the [C99 Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html).

Comment: In the C standard  , the section "The fprintf function" gives a full reference. However, for the stuff about matching arguments to a function with `...` in the prototype (of which `printf` is one) you also need to read 6.5.2.2.#6-7  (Function calls)

Comment: Linux man pages also have some documentation (although quality varies)